# Proper use of @since and @copyright in docblock headers?

Tags: joomla-3.x, docblock

The [DocBlocks](http://joomla.github.io/coding-standards/?coding-standards/chapters/docblocks.md) section of the Coding Standards Manual is mostly self-explanatory, but I've never been sure about two elements - `since` and `copyright`.

`since` - is that for the Joomla version or my component's (arbitrary) version number? Probably the former, but I'd like to be certain.

`copyright` is a little more tricky. It's obvious if it's a method or class I've built from scratch, but what if half the code's come from a Joomla component? What if all I did was add a line? I've no idea what to put in the copyright element in situations where authorship is mixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@since` should be used to state the version that your component implemented this specific function/class/property/etc..

For example:

```
/**
 * This function does something
 *
 * @since 1.2
 *
 */

public function foo()
{
    // do something
}
```

This above means you added the `foo()` function in `v1.2` of your extension.

Depending on how you build and release your extension, you can also use a constant, like Joomla do, for example: `@since _DEPLOY__VERSION_`

Joomla build released through command line. The version is set when building, which then un turn, replaces all instances of `_DEPLOY__VERSION_`

---

As for `@copyright`, for me personally, there are 2 scenarios.

**If I've copied an entire file and made some tweaks:**

```
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 * 
 * Modified by NAME
 */
class Foo {
    public function bar() {};
}
```

**If I've written my own class and copied a couple of functions from Joomla**

```
/**
 * @package     MY COMPONENT
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2016 - MY COMPANY
 * @license     MY LICENSE
 */
class Foo {

    /**
     * @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
     */
    public function bar() {};
}
```

---

Hope this helps

Comment: Cheers mate. Since is answered definitively. Your copyright approach is pretty much what I've been doing and is as good an answer as I hoped to get, but in all honesty given it's a tag that has an attachment, however distant, to lawyers I'd have appreciated clear guidelines from the Project Team. They really should add a little more detail in the CSM.